# How to use anchors instead of Submit button in Struts2?

Tags: java, struts2, tags

I wish to use anchors instead of submit button in a struts tag form. Can I do it ? How should i create it ?

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anchor using struts tag use this

```
<s:url id="url" action="dummyAction">
     <s:param name="parameterName"><s:property value="parameterValue"/></s:param>
</s:url>
<s:a href="%{url}">Click here</s:a>
```

Comment: will the form parameters be forwarded to the bean properties properly ? I have some textfields in the form. I want their values to enter the bean properties when user clicks the anchor

Comment: Take the help of javascript and populate the <s:param/>'s before clicking the link.. in this way u can sumbit the user input form.

Comment: Take the help of javascript and populate the <s:param/>'s before clicking the link.. in this way u can sumbit the user input form. 
OR
If you want to submit the form using anchor the Call the javascript function onclick of the anchor and use document.forms["myform"].submit(); in the function.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue. My solution was to submit the form data using the jQuery serialize method to append the form data tho the href of the anchor tag.

```
<s:url var="urlFkey" namespace="%{namespace}" action="GotoAddForeignKeyRecord" escapeAmp="false" >
  <s:param name="target" >disp${fieldName}</s:param>
  <s:param name="fkeyName" value="fkeyName"/>
  <s:param name="fkeyTableName" value="fkeyPrimaryTableName"/>
  <s:param name="recordID" value="recordID"/>
</s:url>
<s:a id="disp%{fieldName}" href="%{urlFkey}" cssClass='nyroModal' onclick="this.href = this.href + '&' + $('#%{dispTablename}saveRecord').serialize();">
   Add New <s:property value="fkeyPrimaryTableNameLabel"/>
</s:a>
```

Notice how the serialize method is called in the onclick event for the anchor tag.
You can find more examples of using Struts with jQuery at my blog [here](http://richgski.blogspot.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest just doing a javascript:form.submit() inside your anchor tag href